# Unable to connect to remote debugger

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, remote-debugging

I am building a react native app in Android Emulator Nexus_23. I am trying to connect to the remote debugger but I get a Timeout error. On refreshing I am stuck on a blank white screen.

Tried: 
(1) re-installing Google Chrome too according to a few suggestions on Internet but still facing the same problem. 
(2) I set my ip address ("Dev Settings" -> "Debug server host for device") x.x.x.x:8081
(3) tried adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

react-native: 0.52.0
react: 16.2.0

Kindly help!

[Unable to connect to remote debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9AhO.png)

Comment: Did you tried this stuff -> facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: do you have an internet connection?

Comment: OfCourse I do @Sathish

Comment: I was debugging it remotely...I am facing this problem all of a suddun...may be from three days @JainZz

Comment: react-native and react version ?

Comment: hope this will help you...[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898934/unable-to-connect-with-remote-debugger)

Comment: "react": "16.2.0",    "react-native": "0.52.0"

Comment: go to your project directory in terminal and start your react-native server.

Comment: @Thunder. That worked. I also updated Sdk build tools to v23.0.3. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @SwethaG thanks , can you upvote my answer

Comment: I crossed the reputation threshold just now! Tried yesterday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your **project directory** in **terminal** and **start** your **react-native server** it will work for you.