# Android React native debugging shows unable to connect with remote debugger timeout error

Tags: ubuntu, adb, react-native, genymotion

When I try to connect to debugging it's showing `unable to connect with remote debugger : timeout`

This is the url I am trying to access using Chrome

```
http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/
```

In console I am getting the error as :

```
DeltaDispatcher.js UncaughtSyntax error unexpected token )

 if (!this._initialized && !deltaBundle.reset) {
        throw new Error(
          'DeltaPatcher should receive a fresh Delta when being initialized',
        );
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40898934/1778421

Comment: already cheked.. Not working.

Comment: I was working in Ubuntu, As i tried much i could'nt get through. So I planned to use windows and setup everything that required for windows. And in windows I didnt get this issue.

Comment: Sometimes removing react native and reinstalling in ubuntu may work. Please try this also if anyone get this issue.

Comment: try to give your ip instead of 'localhost'

Comment: I also tried this but i couldnt find the debug page.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this issue, I deleted Node Modules folder and did npm install again and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you were working with more than one RN app and just forgot to close the Chrome debug window, do that first and see.