# Unable to debug in device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging

Hello I'm new to react native. and i'm trying to debug the  code with real device. But every time I'm debug I'm getting an error :

> unable to connect with remote debugger Failed to connect to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:8081

this on my mobile screen. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the error and confirm that the device and packager are on same network.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898934/unable-to-connect-with-remote-debugger

Comment: no my system and device are not connected to same network.

Comment: is this important to connect to same network.

Comment: and also even when i'm opening http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui this link in chrome it's not opening.

Comment: local host refused to connect.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several cases where you can't connect to debugger:

1. Device and host machine definitely should be on the same network. Either connect your mobile to your PC's network or your pc to the mobile hotspot.
2. In some cases on real devices, you might need to run adbe reverse command:

   ```
   adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
   ```
3. Uninstall the app, stop the packager, and restart the packager with reset cache option:

   ```
   npm start -- --reset-cache
   ```

   And then, run it on device again.

Comment: i'm getting this error "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

shake your device and in the menu choose **dev settings**
in **debug server host & port for device** section enter your pc ip address via  port 8081 like this :

```
192.168.1.3:8081
```

Comment: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui :- this link is not opening in my chrome do i need to do some setting in chrome to connect with local host

Comment: use your IP instead of localhost
get your ip by ipconfig in cmd

Comment: i fetch the ip address of my system t

Comment: 192.168.0.11:8081

Comment: i entered this ip address