# Safari iOS debugging with USB shows blank screen

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, safari

My problem is when I connect my iPhone 7 Plus into my Macbook Retina 12' and open "Develop > My Phone > Website That My Phone On Safari", under MacOs Safari it always shows a blank page like in the screenshot below.

[image: Always Blank]

What I have done already;

- My phone is up to date.
- My MacOs up to date.
- I opened Safari Web Inspector from my phone. [image: phoneSettings]
- Deleted Safari Cache from my phone and macOS.

But still, I have the issue. I really appreciate the help, I dig on the internet but couldn't find anything valuable. Don't want to Hard Reset my phone because I have loads of data.

Comment: Might be related to this .Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/49003356/8565152

Comment: Didn't get it for macos and safari, what would it need localhost for usb debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is having the same issue here is the solution;

The problem was safari version misalignment between phone. If you download safari technology preview it will solve your issue 
https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/