# Metro bundler: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

When I reload my bundle this exception is uncaught:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:592:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:366:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:403:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (/home/brady/obs-websocket-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:347:17)
    at new UnableToResolveError (/home/brady/obs-websocket-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:333:35)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/brady/obs-websocket-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/brady/obs-websocket-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
    at /home/brady/obs-websocket-app/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42
    at /home/brady/obs-websocket-app/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1471:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

My `package.json`

```
{
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.0",
    "obs-websocket-js": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.64.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.12.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.3.0",
    "jest-expo": "~40.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: What was causing this error here was the remote debugger, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53158802/6585238) helped

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently there's an issue with moving `index.js` to `src/index.js`. I moved it back to the project root and it's working fine now.

Comment: In my project, index.js is in root but still facing the issue. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure about your case. This was the only change that fixed it for me.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't my issue. My `index.js` already lives in the root. I'm still looking for a solution. I've read elsewhere that it could be a problem with using `react-native-animated`. This error is new for me. Until today, I was able to launch the simulator in `debug` mode. Now, the app launches correctly normally and hangs with this "illegal operation" metro error. Disabling debug allows the app to reload/launch normally.

Comment: nope, also didn't do it for me

Comment: The `index.js` was missing, don't know when I deleted it, but after recovering it things worked again.

Answer (score 13):

Replace this code in `MainApplication.java

```js
        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "src/index"; <---add this
        }
```

Comment: How to do this but for IOS?

Comment: If you are using a monorepo (my case) and getting this problem, changing this to something like `packages/my-project/index` works like a charm.

Comment: it is not work for me

Answer (score 10):

### For IOS

```m
// packages/myapp/ios/myapp/AppDelegate.m:56
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"src/index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

Comment: was containing: `jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"`

Comment: If you are using a monorepo (my case) and getting this problem, changing this to something like `packages/my-project/index` works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by deleting and creating new android emulator...

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, but all going well after I `yarn global remove wml`

```
yarn global remove wml
```

that save my life

if you have never install `wml`, just consider some other related global libs

----update-----
I got the error again even I uninstall `wml` staff, but I found my issue's root cause was the `watchman`, after run `brew uninstall watchman`, all going well

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31409664)

Answer (score 0):

An old instance of the remote debugger running caused this for me. Not sure of the "whys", but if you want to kill the debugger programmatically, add this to the top of your App.tsx or whatever your top-level entry file is:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
NativeModules.DevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(false);
```

Credit to Christophe Marois over at this answer [How to disable Remote JS Debugging in React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719321/how-to-disable-remote-js-debugging-in-react-native)

Answer (score -3):

If you are using `create-react-native-library` for native modules and getting this error. Do the following:

1. `cd example`
2. `npx react-native start`
3. In rootDir, `yarn example run`